# Assignin Evalin into Matlab variable struct

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm trying to modify my `Farzeug` structure from inside a gui `popupmenu`. I'm trying to use the `assignin` function.

```
contents = get(hObject,'Value')
 Klima_Regler_GUI = evalin('base','Fahrzeug.Klima_Regler'); 
 switch contents
  case 1
      Klima_Regler_GUI = 1;
      assignin('base','Fahrzeug.Klima_Regler',Klima_Regler_GUI);
  case 2
      Klima_Regler_GUI = 0.75;
      assignin('base','Fahrzeug.Klima_Regler',Klima_Regler_GUI);
  case 3
       Klima_Regler_GUI = 0.50;
      assignin('base','Fahrzeug.Klima_Regler',Klima_Regler_GUI);
  case 4
       Klima_Regler_GUI= 0.25;
      assignin('base','Fahrzeug.Klima_Regler',Klima_Regler_GUI);
 case 5
       Klima_Regler_GUI = 0;
       assignin('base','Fahrzeug.Klima_Regler',Klima_Regler_GUI);  
 otherwise
```

but I keep getting this error:

[image: error]

I will appreciate any help

Comment: Please post errors as text, as images are hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to change the structure field using `assignin` because

> assignin(ws, 'var', val) assigns the value val to the variable var in the workspace ws. The var input must be the array name only; it cannot contain array indices.

But you can use `evalin` to do this:

```
evalin('base',['Fahrzeug.Klima_Regler = ' num2str(Klima_Regler_GUI)])
```